# Supply stop / valve crooked piece - dangerous?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

I had a contractor come in and totally botch a simple toilet installation which I'm going to have to pay a proper plumber to come fix up. He replaced a supply stop / valve and upon inspection it seems to have a crooked piece. Is this dangerous or is that element just decorative?

[Part on company website](https://www.dahlvalve.com/products/mini-ball-valves/supply-stops/copper/supply-stops-511-33-31.php)

As installed by the contractor: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manufacturer, that part is called the Stopcap and it limits the handle rotation to 90°.  Simply tapping it back into place is the solution to the problem.  However, this might not always be the case, see JACK's answer if your valve model is different.

Answer (score 5):

That collar has been cross threaded. It might have been done at the factory because that's not something that the installer would be undoing. They might be tightening it up but that's all. You might be able to loosen it up, after turning off the house water main, and straighten out the threads. As is, it has the potential to leak and wouldn't be able to be tightened.

I'd get the contractor back and have him replace it. You could also replace it, you'd need an adjustable wrench and would need to turn off the water at the house main.

Comment: Is it dangerous in its current state?  I plan to have a plumber come and fix everything up but it won't be for a few days.

Comment: @MarcGuay  Dangerous to life and limb?, no.  Just the possibility of leaking.

Comment: So there's no chance of it popping off and flooding the house?  Does the possiblity of leakage still exist if the valve is closed?  Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: @MarcGuay      If it's not leaking now, there's a good chance it won't start anytime soon. Cross threading can be pretty tight so I doubt it will pop off. Since the collar isn't fastened down correctly, the valve could still leak because the valve stem might not be straight into the valve base. Like I said though, if it's not leaking not, you should be OK.

Comment: According to the plumber who is here now, the collar is decorative (not threaded on) and he just tapped it back into place.

Comment: @MarcGuay  Woo Hoo!